# How to get the rest of the split array to convert to a string on java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse

so i have split a string from a users input.

```
String p = blah.nextLine();
String[] pizzaArr = p.split("");
String s = pizzaArr[0];
String t= *pizzaArr[1][2][3][4]* <=== this is the bit.
```

i want the rest of the array i split without the first element to a string. i have demonstrated this with the elements there , this in fact doesn't work. i need this  so i can use it in a switch (has to be a string)

Comment: `p.substring(1)`

Comment: can you post an input output example... are you sure you want to split to ""

Answer (score 2):

```
String t= "";
for(int i = 1; i < pizzaArr.length; i++) {
    t += pizzaArr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use scanner to take input string and split the string using `split()` method. `split("")` method split your string by one char. since your question is unclear, so what i understand is , use first char as a switch case. See the demo :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Ataur
 */
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String p = sc.nextLine();
        String[] pizzaArr = p.split("");
        String output ="";
        String switchStr = p.substring(0, 1);
        for(int i= 1; i< pizzaArr.length;i++){
            output+=pizzaArr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("This is the original String = "+output);
        switch(switchStr){
            case "1":{
                System.out.println("In the switch case statement");
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("this is default statement");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use `String#join` along with `Arrays#copyOfRange`:

```
String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(pizzaArr, 1, pizzaArr.length));
```

Note how it uses a single character of white-space as the delimiter; this can be changed by simply changing the first parameter of `String#join` to whatever you'd like!